# "An instance method you define in a category of the NSObject class might be performed not only by instances but by class objects as well

Tags: iphone

Can you explain "An instance method you define in a category of the NSObject class might be performed not only by instances but by class objects as well", i have come across this sentence while reading an Objective C guide...! But i am not able to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Instance method is a method you can call on an object (as opposed to a class). Each object is an *instance* of a certain class (just as each of us is an instance of a human<sup>1</sup>), that’s why we talk about *instance methods*. For example when you say `[someArray count]`, you are calling an instance method called `count` on some array object (= instance of the `NSArray` class).

Class methods are called on classes, for example `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` is a class method of the `UIApplication` class. You can’t call an instance method on a class, nor can you call a class method on an object.

Category is a way to extend behaviour of existing classes, a kind of plugin you stick on an existing class. For example by writing this:

```
@interface NSObject (SampleCategory)
- (void) sayFoo;
@end

@implementation NSObject (SampleCategory)

- (void) sayFoo {
    NSLog(@"Foo!");
}

@end
```

…you make it possible to call `[anObject sayFoo]` on any object derived from `NSObject`. And now we are getting to the point of the sentence: `NSObject` seems to be special, because when you declare an instance method of `NSObject` using a category (such as our `sayFoo`), you can call this method even as a class method: `[NSObject sayFoo]`, `[NSView sayFoo]`, etc.

---

1] Sorry, Googlebot!

Comment: Ok, fine. It works for both NSObject class and NSObject reference variable.but I am not getting why it works as class Method ??

Comment: Are you one-hundred-cast-in-concrete percent sure you know the difference between objects, instances, and classes? Or maybe I’m not getting something?

Comment: "NSObject seems to be special, because when you declare an instance method of NSObject using a category (such as our sayFoo), you can call this method even as a class method" It's not special; it's just because it's the root class. If you define your own root class, the same would be true of classes descended from it. Metaclasses (the class of class objects) follow an inheritance pattern that ultimately descends from the root class.